# How to "reinstall and reload" a local R package?

Tags: r

I'm implementing a statistical algorithm into an R package, which will be used in my analysis. The R package is local on my disk.

Since I'm making a lot of changes to the R package, I want my analysis script to reinstall and reload the fresh R package every time it runs.

What's the best way to do this? Currently, I use:

```
install.packages("~/my_package/", repos=NULL, type="source") 
library("my_package")
```

However, it seems like I still have to manually tell Rstudio to restart my R session for the fresh version to kick in.

Comment: You probably need to detatch the package first `detach("package:my_package", unload=TRUE)`

Comment: @Mako212 if you want to post an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to unload the current version of the package for the update to take effect when you try to load it again.

```
detach("package:my_package", unload=TRUE)
```

> Note: `package` is literal, `my_package` = insert your package name here

```
library(dplyr)
detach("package:dplyr", unload=TRUE)
```

If a package is already loaded `library()` doesn't load it again. You can see this by running

```
library(dplyr, verbose=TRUE)
library(dplyr, verbose=TRUE)
```

The first time you run this command it loads the package, the second time it returns:

```
Warning message:
In library(dplyr, verbose = T) :
  package ‘dplyr’ already present in search()
```

`library()` uses a generalized form of `is.na(match("package:dplyr",search()))` to determine whether a package is attached or not, and so running `library()` alone won't update the currently loaded package since this check doesn't differentiate between package versions.

Also worth noting that you'll have to first `unload` any dependencies, otherwise you'll see an error to the effect of:

> Warning message:
> ‘dplyr’ namespace cannot be unloaded:
> namespace ‘dplyr’ is imported by <package(s)> so cannot be unloaded

Comment: Maybe obvious to others, but in `detach("package:my_package")`, the `package:` part is literal. For example to detach `BreakoutDetection` I did `detach("package:BreakoutDetection")`.

Comment: I think you need to do extra work to reload packages with dynamic libraries: https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/119